# nagios does not send emalis

Tags: postfix-mta, nagios

I'm trying to setup email notifications on a nagios server. The nagios machine has been running okay for a little while now. Except for the fact that it hasn't been sending emails. I've been using a chrome plugin in it's place until I get this resolved.

Anyhow, this is how I have my contacts file setup:

```
define contact{
       contact_name                     nagiosadmin             ; Short name of user
       use                              generic-contact         ; Inherit default values from generic-contact template (defined above)
       alias                            Nagios Admin            ; Full name of user
       email                            admin@example.com;      <<***** CHANGE THIS TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS ******
       service_notification_period      24x7
       host_notification_period         24x7
       service_notification_options     w,u,c,r,f
       host_notification_options        d,u,r,f
       service_notification_commands    notify-service-by-email
       host_notification_commands       notify-host-by-email
       }


define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name       admins
    alias                   Nagios Administrators
    members                 nagiosadmin
    }
```

And I have my host and service definitions setup like this:

```
define host{
    use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                                                    ; This host definition will inherit all variables that are defined
                                                    ; in (or inherited by) the linux-server host template definition.
    host_name               web1
    alias                   web1
    address                 10.10.10.6
    contact_groups          admins
    }


define service{
    use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       web1
    service_description             HTTP
    contact_groups                  admins
    check_command                   check_http
    notifications_enabled           1
    }
```

I've tested if this works by shutting down http on a web server it's monitoring. Waited a while and no message received on the mail server.

I've also telnetted to the mail server on the nagios machine. And I'm able to send an email to the account I want via telnet.

I'd appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your service notification command configuration and execute it  in a terminal for debugging.

Example : 

`define command {
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n $NOTIFICATIONCOMMENT$\n" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}`